# JAX-RS Put method with multiple parameters

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

This is my JAX-RS Put method. I use multiple parameters in here .

```
@Path("/Add")
public class AddJSONService {
    @PUT
    @Path("/deactivateAdd/{idAdd}/{activeStatus}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void deactivateAdd(@PathParam("idAdd") int idAdd, @PathParam("activeStatus") boolean activeStatus) {

        AddInterface addInterface = new AddTable();
        addInterface.deactivateAdd(idAdd, activeStatus);
    }

}
```

When I run this method, browser brings me following message .

**HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed** .

Have any ideas about this ?

**UPDATED**- idAllergy to idAdd.

Comment: What is the URL that you tried?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Balance_Rest/rest/Add/deactivateAdd/3/false

Comment: Use a rest client like Postman, instead of browser. Through browser you do GET instead of PUT

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are using a custom browser plugin, e.g. Postman, the browser will always do a HTTP GET when you enter an URL. Your method is specified to accept only PUT requests, and so the request is rejected.

Comment: With the information you've provided thus far, this is likely the cause. You can't do PUT straight from a browser. And unless you construct a HTML form, you can't do POST either. If you just type the URL or click a bookmark, that's a GET, which your service does not support.

Answer (score 0):

`@PathParam` should match the path parameters. `idAllergy` -> `idAdd`

`public void deactivateAdd(@PathParam("idAdd") int idSomething, @PathParam("activeStatus") boolean activeStatus)`

Comment: Sorry for the mistake I've update my post please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake with the idAdd parameter.

Could you try with :

```
@Path("/Add")
public class AddJSONService {
    @PUT
    @Path("/deactivateAdd/{idAdd}/{activeStatus}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void deactivateAdd(@PathParam("idAdd") int idAdd, @PathParam("activeStatus") boolean activeStatus) {

        AddInterface addInterface = new AddTable();
        addInterface.deactivateAdd(idAdd, activeStatus);
    }

}
```

UPDATED: Why are you using PUT instead POST annotation in the webservice? If I understood well, you are not doing a PUT in the browser, isn't that?

Comment: I am going to update the Add table in my database . So I think PUT is the best . Is it ok ?

Comment: If you are not uploading any kind of files, I would prefer to use Post. How are you testing the service with Put? Are you using some kind of extension in your browser? Could you post that?

Comment: Actually I am not using any kind of extension in my browser.

Comment: For the POST result is same

Comment: By default the browser only do GET requests. You should use an extension for your browser to test it...